# display one row records in to multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a table which consists of Fiscal Weekending and Fiscal Year with all the weekending data and both FY17 and FY18 years. below is how its shows in the sql table.

```
Fiscal Week Ending  Fiscal Year
20161112    FY17
20161126    FY17
20161210    FY17
20170204    FY17
20170218    FY17
20170304    FY17
20170318    FY17
20170401    FY17
20170520    FY17
20170603    FY17
20170722    FY17
20170805    FY17
20170819    FY17
20170902    FY17
20171021    FY17
20171104    FY17
20171111    FY18
20171230    FY18
20180120    FY18
20180203    FY18
20180303    FY18
20180421    FY18
20180505    FY18
20180623    FY18
20180707    FY18
20180721    FY18
20180804    FY18
20161224    FY17
20161231    FY17
20170107    FY17
20170114    FY17
20170121    FY17
20170325    FY17
20170909    FY17
20170916    FY17
20170923    FY17
20171007    FY17
20180407    FY18
20180602    FY18
20180609    FY18
20180616    FY18
20161119    FY17
20161203    FY17
20161217    FY17
20170128    FY17
20170211    FY17
20170225    FY17
20170311    FY17
20170429    FY17
20170513    FY17
20170527    FY17
20170610    FY17
20170729    FY17
20170812    FY17
20170930    FY17
20171014    FY17
20171028    FY17
20171104    FY18
20171223    FY18
20180113    FY18
20180127    FY18
20180331    FY18
20180414    FY18
20180428    FY18
20180512    FY18
20180630    FY18
20180714    FY18
20161105    FY17
20170408    FY17
20170415    FY17
20170422    FY17
20170506    FY17
20170617    FY17
20170624    FY17
20170701    FY17
20170708    FY17
20170715    FY17
20170826    FY17
20171118    FY18
20171125    FY18
20171202    FY18
20171209    FY18
20171216    FY18
20180106    FY18
20180210    FY18
20180217    FY18
20180224    FY18
20180310    FY18
20180317    FY18
20180324    FY18
20180519    FY18
20180526    FY18
20180728    FY18
```

What i am looking for is to display the data like below.

```
FY17    FY18
20161112    20171111
20161126    20171230
20161210    20180120
20170204    20180203
20170218    20180303
20170304    20180421
20170318    20180505
20170401    20180623
20170520    20180707
20170603    20180721
20170722    20180804
20170805    20180407
20170819    20180602
20170902    20180609
20171021    20180616
20171104    20171104
20161224    20171223
20161231    20180113
20170107    20180127
20170114    20180331
20170121    20180414
20170325    20180428
20170909    20180512
20170916    20180630
20170923    20180714
20171007    20171118
20161119    20171125
20161203    20171202
20161217    20171209
20170128    20171216
20170211    20180106
20170225    20180210
20170311    20180217
20170429    20180224
20170513    20180310
20170527    20180317
20170610    20180324
20170729    20180519
20170812    20180526
20170930    20180728
20171014    
20171028    
20161105    
20170408    
20170415    
20170422    
20170506    
20170617    
20170624    
20170701    
20170708    
20170715    
20170826
```

Can any one help me with SQL statment how to do this.

Comment: Sample data is great. But is really that much of it needed?

Answer (score 1):

If your database type & version supports the window functions,
then you can use ROW_NUMBER to get a number.
A number based on the FiscalWeekEnd per FiscalYear.

After that you can pivot via conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
 MAX(CASE WHEN FiscalYear = 'FY17' THEN FiscalWeekEnding END) AS FY17,
 MAX(CASE WHEN FiscalYear = 'FY18' THEN FiscalWeekEnding END) AS FY18
FROM
(
  SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Fiscal Year" ORDER BY "Fiscal Week Ending") AS RN,
   "Fiscal Year" AS FiscalYear,
   "Fiscal Week Ending" AS FiscalWeekEnding 
  FROM yourtable
  WHERE "Fiscal Year" IN ('FY17','FY18')
) q
GROUP BY RN
ORDER BY RN
```